# implementing google maps directions with ionic 1

Tags: javascript, html, api, ionic-framework, direction

I followed this tutorial on youtube here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gw3AKC4MsGQ

I have done everything the same but have come to a slight problem as the javascript has been updated since the video was made. Any ideas on what changes should be made to my code to accommodate the changes in the javascript?

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
 <title></title>

 <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

 <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
 <script>
   if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
     navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
       .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
       .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
   }
</script>-->

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCMsQzZKDhyiXUMOxllFxi5iBz1tZ1j-mc&callback=initMap">
</script>
<script type="js/direction.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Get Directions</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
     <div id="map"></div> 
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

And this is the Javascript:

```
function initMap() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var onChangeHandler = function() {
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    };
    document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  }

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route({
      origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
      destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain what your problem is?

Comment: sorry, the map will not load in the localhost on my web browser when using "ionic serve" in the command terminal

Answer (score 1):

type="js/direction.js", it will be src="js/direction.js"

Comment: Dear Vivek please proved full answer, or update of the code.these type of concise answers should be done through comment otherwise causes confusion